# Lagrange error in Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[question 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhCz5.jpg)

I've tried solving this but I get $n = 4$ instead of $n = 5$ which is the right answer.
I used the

> lagrange remainder $\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(z)(x-c)^{n+1}$

I plugged in 1 for the $f^{(n)}(z)$ and 1.2 for $x$ and then solved until the inequality became true which was at $n=4$

is the problem something to do with $n+1$ vs $n$ in the lagrange remainder equation?

Comment: What value did you get when you did n=4?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks the number of terms not $n$. Number of terms is $ n+1$.

...

Edit: The error $E$ is given by the following upper bound formula
$$E\leq \frac{|f^{(n+1)}(z)|}{(n+1)!}|x-x_0|^{n+1}$$
for some $z$ specified by Lagrange's theorem. We are given $|f^{(n+1)}(z)|\leq1$ for all $z$ and $x=1.2, x_0=1.$ The questions wants $E<10^{-5}.$ Combined with the formula we have the inequality $\frac{(0.2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<10^{-5}$ which is true for $n\geq 4.$

Therefore the minimum degree Taylor's polynomial needed is
$$T_4(x)=\color{purple}{f(1)}+\color{blue}{f'(1)(x-1)}+\color{red}{\frac12 f''(1)(x-1)^2}+\color{purple}{\frac16f'''(1)(x-1)^3}+\color{green}{\frac1{24}f^{(4)}(x-1)^4}$$
which has $5$ terms.